# How can I generalise a function that accepts an `&[T]` so that I can still invoke it with a bytestring literal?

Tags: rust, slice, traits

I started off with a function a bit like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0Afn%20find%20%3CT%3A%20Copy%3E%20(src%3A%20%26%5BT%5D%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20src%5Bindex%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20b%22abc%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(b%27b%27%2C%20find(x%2C%201))%3B%0A%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn find <T: Copy> (src: &[T], index: usize) -> T {
    // more complex algorithm, involving src goes here
    src[index]
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = b"abc";
    assert_eq!(b'b', find(x, 1));    
}
```

And I wanted to generalise it so that I can use any appropriate type for `src`. The best I came up with is this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=trait%20RandomAccess%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_at(%26self%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20Copy%3E%20RandomAccess%3CT%3E%20for%20%5BT%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_at(%26self%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%5Bindex%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20find%3CT%3A%20Copy%2C%20S%3A%20%3FSized%20%2B%20RandomAccess%3CT%3E%3E(src%3A%20%26S%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20src.get_at(index)%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Apub%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20b%22xyz%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(b%27y%27%2C%20find(%26x%5B..%5D%2C%201))%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
trait RandomAccess<T> {
    fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T;
}

impl <T: Copy> RandomAccess<T> for [T] {
    fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T {
        self[index]
    }
}

fn find <T: Copy, S: ?Sized + RandomAccess<T>> (src: &S, index: usize) -> T {
    // more complex algorithm, involving src goes here
    src.get_at(index)
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = b"xyz";
    assert_eq!(b'y', find(&x[..], 1));
}
```

However, I now can't just invoke `find(x, 1)`, I have to create a slice: `find(&x[..], 1)`.

Is there a way to make this generic, but still be able to invoke `find` as in the original example?

Comment: It seems like the rust compiler is doing some trickery behind the scenes in the first example, and allowing `&[u8; 3]` to be coerced to `&[u8]`, but cannot do this in the second example because it cannot know for sure that this is the intention. Is that basically the issue?

Comment: I tried abstracting over Index<usize> and some other stuff, but I'm unconvinced that you need to introduce such abstractions at all - they tend to complicate things without added value. What are the other `src` types `find()` can apply to?

Comment: The trickery is that: coercions trigger if the destination type is known. Since `find` is using a type parameter for `src`, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example doesn't currently work due to a limitation in the rust compiler (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29504). However, there are a few ways around this.

The simplest way is to implement `RandomAccess<T>` for all `C: AsRef<[T]>`. This way, it'll work with `[T; n]`, `&[T]`, `Vec<T>`, etc.:

```
trait RandomAccess<T> {
    fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T;
}

impl<T: Copy, C: AsRef<[T]>> RandomAccess<T> for C {
    fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T {
        self.as_ref()[index]
    }
}

fn find<T: Copy, C: RandomAccess<T>>(src: C, index: usize) -> T {
    src.get_at(index)
}
```

Unfortunately, you won't be able to add any other `RandomAccess` impls if you do that so you might as well just change `find` to take some collection satisfying `AsRef<[T]>`:

```
fn find<T: Copy, C: AsRef<[T]>> (src: C, index: usize) -> T {
    src.get_at(index)
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to be able to support collections that *can't* be borrowed as `[T]`, you can implement `RandomAccess<T>` for `[T; n]` for all `n` in some range using a macro:

```
trait RandomAccess<T> {
    fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T;
}

impl<T: Copy> RandomAccess<T> for [T] {
    fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T {
        self[index]
    }
}

macro_rules! impl_random_access {
    ($($n:expr,)*) => {
        $(
            impl <T: Copy> RandomAccess<T> for [T; $n] {
                fn get_at(&self, index: usize) -> T {
                    self[index]
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}

impl_random_access! {
    01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,
    09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
    17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,
    25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,
}



fn find<T: Copy, S: ?Sized + RandomAccess<T>>(src: &S, index: usize) -> T {
    src.get_at(index)
}
```

When we eventually get type-level constants (currently on the wish-list), you should be able to just implement `RandomAccess<T>` for all `[T; n]`. But for now, you'll need to use a macro.

Comment: `AsRef` has the same limitation of being only implemented up to `[T; 32]`.

Comment: Can you explain the mechanism by which the simpler version (`fn find <T:> (src: &[T])`) works? Is it a special case of the compiler to coerce `&[T; n]` to `&[T]`?

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29504. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes, it's built-in